# element not added when push in array

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to push an array into other array but it does not work. Also, i have tried with array_push and does not work

```
    foreach($cartitemCollection as $cartitem){
        foreach($cartitem['product'] as $product){
            $variablePrices = $variablePricesRepository->findByProductId($product['id']);
            $product['var_price'] = $variablePrices; //not working
            array_push( $product,$variablePrices ); //also not working
        }   
    }
```

Comment: you are right @MarkusZeller!! you the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On next iteration product will be overwritten. But you can use a [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). *Note the ampersand.*

```php
foreach($cartitemCollection as $cartitem){
    foreach($cartitem['product'] as &$product){
        $variablePrices = $variablePricesRepository->findByProductId($product['id']);
        $product['var_price'] = $variablePrices;
    }
}
```